# Javascript - get first RegExp match with matchAll()

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I'm happy to admit that javascript isn't my strongest language.  I test my regexs in a little .net tester I wrote years ago, and I see no problems there.  I know different languages implement regex a little differently, but I don't think that's the issue here.

My app has a textarea where I can paste in data from an industry-specific spreadsheet and I use regexp matchAll() to parse. I am looping through the matchAll-returned iterable with a for/of loop, pretty basic stuff, and noticed that I can't seem to get the first match.  So If my spreadsheet has 15 lines of data, my javascript parsing handles lines 2-15 ignoring #1.  If I copy any lines in the block and paste them to the start then the new line #1 is ignored and the old #1 which is now #2 gets parsed, always ignoring the first line.  So the issue is apparently not the RegExp pattern.  I googled and found this passage from developer.mozilla.org:

> matchAll only returns the first match if the /g flag is missing

this says to me that if I take out the /g I will only get the first match, but I guess this sentence could also be read to mean

> unless the /g flag is missing, matchAll will not return the first match

but that would be ridiculous, right? if I take out the /g then I get the first match, and only the first match.  if I use /g I get matches 2-15.  Why can't I get 1-15? I copied some of my code from a different app I made a few months ago that doesn't have this issue.

working code:

```
var patt = /(?<invoiceNumber>INV \d+)\t(?<vendor>[\w  .,&-]+)\t(?<vendInvNum>[ ()\w\d\/.-]+)\t(20)?(?<yr>\d{2})[-\/](?<mn>\d{1,2})[-\/](?<dd>\d{1,2})\tInvoice\sUSD\s+(?<invAmt>[\d,.-]+)/g

for (let result of objInp.value.matchAll(patt)){
    //loops thru iterable
}
```

example of data pasted in, finds 3 for 3 matches:

```
INV 006015  VENDOR 1    1025702 26/08/2019  Invoice USD  580.69 
INV 006019  VENDOR 2    STORE/090919    09/09/2019  Invoice USD  38.71 
INV 006021  Vendor 3    170241569   10/09/2019  Invoice USD  1,080.64
```

Code that doesn't pull in first match:

```
var patt = /\s(?<actID>[\w\d-]+)\t(?<actDesc>[\w\d  .,&\(\)-]+)?\t(?<origDur>[\d]+)?\t(?<start>[-\d\w]+)?\t(?<end>[-\d\w]+)?/g

for (let result of objInp.value.matchAll(patt[x])){
    //loops through but always misses the first match
}
```

example of pasted data, finds 2 out of 3 matches:

```
Activity ID Activity Name   Original Duration   Start   Finish  Variance - BL1 Finish Date  BL1 Finish  Total Float
        S600-20-21  Executive Steering Committee    5   06-Jan-20   13-Jan-20   0   13-Jan-20   0
        S600-20-31  Steering Committee - Option Selection Meeting   2   13-Jan-20   15-Jan-20   0   15-Jan-20   0
        S600-20-019b10  Resource Center of Excellence- Review   20  15-Jan-20   12-Feb-20   0   12-Feb-20   0
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're only getting 2 out of 3 matches because it's the first item and not because the regexp doesn't match? It'd be great to see a full code snippet which can easily reproduce the issue (including the data; I think the tab characters aren't coming through here)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Your RegExp seems to work fine with the sample data you've given: https://jsfiddle.net/jrunning/pfv7t15u/

Comment: the industry-standard spreadsheet starts with 8 space characters, not tabs.  Checking Jordan's jsfiddle...

Comment: Think I found the problem.  didnt realize this would be a problem, but that's what I get for using a language I dont understand completely.  I had put in a if (patt.test() early on during troubleshooting.  that used to be used to loop through matches, so it probably takes off the first match, right?